# The Navras mantra used in Matrix 3. Mantras religious context

Tags: the-matrix, religion, music

At the end of Matrix Revolutions (Matrix 3), before the words "it is done", the Hindu mantra [Navras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navras) is [played](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOtoIBrBAYE).  What context is Navras usually placed in?  How do the Hindus view the mantra and how is it used, i.e. in ceremonial uses? Since Matrix universe is very much a mixed bag I do not think it has very much meaning in Matrix 3. Other than being a nice way of tying things together and to create a nice atmosphere.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand your question, but I'm guessing the answer is very similar to this question's answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12588/are-there-buddhist-influences-in-the-matrix

Comment: Better now? Hope so. Yes, but a quite more specific than your linked one. My question is basically how a tune is used in traditional ceremony. Not about buddism in general. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Use roll back to view my private thoughts on Matrix in approx. 1200 words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a hindu myself, The mantra that u speak of is actually called "Navras" and not "Narvas". This song is from the Brhadaranyaka Upanishad, a philosophical text, with the famous shloka "Asatoma Sat gamaya" which in sanskrit means "Lead us from the unreal to the real". There is also a very elaborate translation by Swami Vivekananda on this upanishad which you should check out here - http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/brdup/brhad_intro.html.

P.S : The tune that is potrayed in the matrix credits is not how its used in traditional ceremonies.

Comment: I suspect they have changed it. To something their 'spot audience' is more used to. Now it sound like a gregorian hymn, to me very much alike those hymns sung by monks in Notre Dame Cathedral in Paris.

Comment: Your blog design is a new favorite of mine.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But i havent heard the hymns sung by the monks in the Notre Dame Cathedral. I like the song, in a different way aside from the religious/philosphical context. Also, thank you for the blog comment!

Comment: Well. Gregorian music is old, catholic church music? Not an expert in anything so don't take my word for it. 2 good examples. [Kyrie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y47JdUI_PhE) and [Messe de Nostre Dame](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y1O-BcZQwY). Guess mantras are older still.